# MPAndroidChart inputted date as x axis?

Tags: android, android-studio, mpandroidchart

I want to make my datepicker X Axis input as a date format in MPandroidchart. I already made my own X axis format but i think i got it wrong because the x axis only show "01"s. [here's what my x axis right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JKz9.jpg)

Here's my x axis code for MainActivity.java:

```
ValueFormatter xAxisFormatter = new AxisValueFormatter();
    XAxis xAxis = lineChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f); 
    xAxis.setLabelCount(7);
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(xAxisFormatter);
```

Here's my array method in MainActivity.java

```
 private ArrayList<Entry> getDataValues() {
    ArrayList<Entry> dataVals = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] columns = {"tanggalsewaktu", "tracksewaktu"};
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query("track_sewaktu", columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        cursor.moveToNext();
       dataVals.add(new Entry(cursor.getLong(0)/100000, cursor.getInt(1)));
    }

    return dataVals;
}
```

And here's my code for AxisValueFormatter.java:

```
public class AxisValueFormatter extends ValueFormatter {

@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
    // convertedTimestamp = originalTimestamp - referenceTimestamp
    Date date = new Date((long)value);
    //Specify the format you'd like
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd", Locale.getDefault());

   return sdf.format(date);

}
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: you are passing the same date (with diff time) in x axis, AxisValueFormatter class is formating your datetime to date formate with only day part (in your case it is 01)

Comment: Im sorry, i dont get the idea. So what exacty i have to do to fix it?

Comment: does your chart use for hourly report or daily report? Based on that you have to prepare you x and y-axis data, it seems like you are providing data for the hourly reports.

Comment: I use the chart for daily report. so when I input the x value, i want it to display the date of the day of the input